# Ho to do the automation to calculate the quantity left, profit and loss when there is new data input in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, automation

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 4 ranges of data:

- `A1:C5` (Product In Storage), there will be new data input if there are other new products coming in.
- `E1:G8` (Sales), this is the record for all the products that are being sold, there will be new data input also in the future.
- `I1:K5` (Summary of Sales), this will record the `Quantity Left` in the storage and also the total `Profit or Loss` after doing some calculation based on `A1:C5` and `E1:G8`. The number of rows for `Summary of Sales` should be equal to the number of rows of `Product In Storage` (So I'm using query function highlighted in yellow).
- `M1:O5` (Desired Output), this is the final result that I want to achieve for this task.

My goal is to calculate the `Quantity Left` & `Profit or Loss` in `Summary of Sales` automatically once there are new data input in `Product In Storage` & `Sales`.

I'm not sure how to do it because the number of rows in `Sales` is a not a constant. In this example, the are 2 rows data for `Product ID: 1001.01` & 3 rows data for `Product ID: 1002.01`. In the future, after the remaining quantity (34) for `Product ID: 1001.01` had been sold, it need to be included in the `Summary of Sales` as well.

I attached the google sheet link below in case you need it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17coke3-oyDRLHgz79PDl3KX68kFOEte-aynVe-xEITU/edit?usp=sharing

Is there anyway to do this without using the google apps script? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example,
J4 -> `=SUMIF(A:A,I4,C:C) - SUMIF(E:E,I4,G:G)` means;

- (First sumif, get inventory) Whenever you see I4 in A:A column, get the C value on that row and sum all of them.
- (And minus)
- (Second sumif, minus sales) Whenever you see I4 in E:E column, get the G value on that row and sum all of them.
- (Result) = Get storage quantity and substitute the sales quantity.

K4 -> `=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(IF(E:E=I4,F:F*G:G)) - SUMPRODUCT(IF(A:A=I4,B:B*C:C)))`
means,

- (get income) if you see I4 on E:E column, then get the sum of (F*G)
- (minus)
- (get expense) if you see I4 on A:A column, then get the sum of (B*C)

But if i were you, to keep things more simple, i would put `=Quantity*Price` right of your tables and you can solve problems with only `=SUMIF` formulas. FYI, this will update everytime you change a value from table so when things get nastier, it will become slower indeed. When that time comes, a VBA macro button or Formulas->Calculation method will save your day.

Comment: Hi ihavenoidea, thanks for your solution! Do you mean create another column `=Quantity*Price`  for `Product In Storage` & `Sales` so that I can use `SUMIF`? Will this reduce the time taken for google sheet to do the calculation when the dataset getting bigger compare to `SUMPRODUCT(IF...)`?

Comment: Well, right now everything is fine. I wanted to say, it would be easier for you if you put `=B4*C4` to D4 and `=F4*G4` to H4 cells. By this way, you don't have to mess with complex formulas like Arrayformula() or if statements. So it would be easier for you to understand.. 

For google's performance, i don't use google sheets so i don't know about it. My suggestion was for local MS Excel sheets performance. Sorry for my bad english :)